# Can't read List from firebase, always returning null on snapshot.data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am trying to read a list from the db and use it on a listview.builder() but before I can do that I need to have data. But the thing is that I DO have data. I have tried this with a String and Int and it works perfectly.

I am reading and setting the users' data as a list to the db. You will notice that I do have a list in the home called 'userDoc', well I needed a way to insert the client info as a list so I thought of doing it like this(if there is a better way please share), but the thing is that it does save it the db, but whenever I refresh the app all the content is gone off-screen but still saved in the db, and when I actually enter new data after refresh it deletes all the old data and replaces it with a new list in the db, which is not what I want(it's suppose to add on to the list with the already existing data).

I am trying to create a simple to-do list by the way. In short, I am having difficulties reading and writing a list to the db, and for some reason, it's returning null when I actually have data in the db. Please tell me if you need more precise information. Thank you.

#### Home

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:innovative_world/services/auth_service.dart";
import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";
import 'package:innovative_world/services/database_service.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/shared/decoration.dart";
import 'package:innovative_world/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/models/user_model.dart";
import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  String _text;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<String> userDoc = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserId>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<UserList>(
        stream: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).userListStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            UserList userList = snapshot.data;
            return Scaffold(


              // App Bar
                  body: // I cut off some irrelevant code
                          RaisedButton( // Submit button
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                                userDoc.add(_text);
                                _formKey.currentState.reset();

                                await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
                                    .setUserData(userDoc);
                              }
                            },
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: userDoc.length,  // snapshot.data.list.length will give Error null
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text(userDoc[index]),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

#### Database service

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import "package:innovative_world/models/list_model.dart";

class DatabaseService {
  // Collection Reference
  CollectionReference listCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("list");

  // Get current users id
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  // Set data to firestore db
  Future setUserData(List<String> list) async {
    return await listCollection.document(uid).setData({ 
      "list": list
    });
  }
  // UserList snapshot
  UserList _userListFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserList(
      uid: uid, 
      list: snapshot.data["list"]
      ); 
  } 
  // Stream for user's to do list
  Stream<UserList> get userListStream {
    return listCollection.document(uid).snapshots()
      .map(_userListFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

#### Auth Service

```
// Register with email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;   

       await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).setUserData(["Test"]); // Set initial Data as snapshot

      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user); 
    }                                     
    catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }

  }
```

#### list model

```
class UserList {

  final List<String> list;
  final String uid;

  UserList({ this.list, this.uid });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've understood, I think you're having a similar problem as I had. First off try seeing what the error is with a small if condition inside your stream builder:

```
if (snapshot.hasError){
   print(snapshot.error.toString);
}
```

If you get an error that says

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'
```

then you have to convert the list to String list. To do that, edit your code in _userListFromSnapshot like this:

```
snapshot.data["list"].cast<String>().toList()
```

Even if you don't get that exact error you're at least one step forward towards fixing it.